# Application to audit wifi security

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to install an application to audit the security of a wifi network.

By audit I mean discover whether current software can bypass my wifi password or read data being transferred.

I know there are some Linux distros that were designed specifically to do that, but I'm looking for an application I can install on Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean by "audit the security"? What are you looking for?

Comment: To see if current softwares can bypass my wifi password or read what is being transfered.

Comment: "some linux distros" We only have answers for official current Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @Rinzwind, the question was edited, i am sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @waltinator , the question was edited, i am sorry if it wasn't clear.  I am asking specifically about Ubuntu.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan , Dont't you think the question is on-topic right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Airack-ng](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/), it's built to pentest WiFi networks, be it encrypted using WEP, WPA, WPA2. As the site describes it:

> It focuses on different areas of WiFi security:
>
> Monitoring: Packet capture and export of data to text files for further processing by third party tools.
>       Attacking: Replay attacks, deauthentication, fake access points and others via packet injection.
>       Testing: Checking WiFi cards and driver capabilities (capture and injection).
>       Cracking: WEP and WPA PSK (WPA 1 and 2).

There's also [Wifite](https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/wifite). It's less complicated than Aircrack-ng. You could just run it like `sudo wifite`, no arguments, and it'll scan for networks. Once you've seen the network you want to pentest, select it by entering its assigned number, then wifite will bruteforce it using different attacks. Personally, I use wifite if the WiFi network is WPS-enabled. Or to get the handshake capture of a WPA/WPA2 WiFi, then pass it along to Aircrack-ng for the dictionary attack.